# Trilateration in 3D with signal strengths

Tags: geodesy

I'm having a hard time getting my head around the maths to locate a target in 3D given a number of known points (4 or more) and a value that indicates the signal strength (range 0–100).

I've looked at the simpler answer in [the 2D case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472469/trilateration-in-a-2d-plane-with-signal-strengths) but I'm unsure how to generalise the idea of normalising the signal strengths for the 3D case. It might even be that this answer is too simple for my requirements. I know that in my case the signal strength is proportional to distance<sup>-2</sup> but do not know the propagation constant.

I've also seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472469/trilateration-in-a-2d-plane-with-signal-strengths), but it's not quite what I'm after as I want to use the signal strengths from a larger number of nodes to improve the estimate.

Comment: Sorry, no answer, but I think if you're trying to improve the estimate (in the overdetermined case), you're going to have to include some form of per-measurement error. Good luck with it.

Comment: You could try to post the same question in http://math.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution here was a simple one. I have a number of signal values, *`S`*, which are proportional to the distance *`d`*:

[image: S = k/f(d)]

<sub>(source: [TeX2img](https://www.bruot.org/tex2img/equations/yliQVd4GoYFjEhTJqbdtYQHnJd2y7hIyMF8Rf53WRYLD/))</sub>

The function *`f`* is known, and the constant *`k`* cancels out in the interpolation, so all that's needed is to apply the inverse of the function to each of the magnitudes before normalisation.

In my case, it means I simply calculate the square root of the signal strengths.